# strings saved on static map are being overriden

Tags: c++, std, static-methods, static-members, stdmap

I have a static class, a static `map<string, int>` is declared on this class.
one of the static methods inserts data to the map, in some point of the process this data is being overridden.

A char is being converted to string and then inserted to the map, like the following:

```
static map <string, int>
int a =10;
const char* arg= "hello";
string toStr(arg);
map.insert(make_pair(toStr, a);
```

What can cause the data to be corrupted?
Does the map point to a pointer of the string(toStr) and not copies it?
If so, are there any other options to save data on map without memory leak? malloc seems to be problematic since there is no option for destructor in order to free the allocated values.

[update]
this is the relevant code, all in the same static class:

```
static map<string, int> levelMap;

static int getLevelFromMap(const char* input)
{

    map<string, int>::const_iterator levelMap_it = levelMap.find((char*)input);
    if ( levelMap_it == levelMap.end() ) {
        return LEVEL_NOT_SET;
    }

    return levelMap_it->second;
}

static void insertToMap(const char* input, int level)
{
    string inputToStr(input);

    levelMap.insert ( make_pair(inputToStr, level) );
}

static int getLevel (const char* input)
{
    int level;

    if (input == NULL)
        return DEFAULT_LEVEL;

    level = getLevelFromMap (input);
    if ( level == LEVEL_NOT_SET ) {
        // Not in the map, check in file
        level = getLevelFromFile (input);

        if (strcmp(input, ROOT_LEVEL) == 0) {
            if (level == NOT_IN_FILE) {
                return level;
            }
            else if (level == LEVEL_NOT_SET) {
                level = DEFAULT_LEVEL;
            }

            insertToMap (ROOT_LEVEL, level);

            return level;
        }

        if (level == NOT_IN_FILE) {
            return DEFAULT_LEVEL;
        }

        if (level == LEVEL_NOT_SET) {

            unsigned int len = ((strlen(ROOT_LEVEL) > strlen(input)) ? strlen(ROOT_LEVEL) : strlen(input)) + 1;
            char parent_input[len];

            int retval = getParent(input, parent_input, sizeof(parent_input));
            if (retval == -1) {
                return DEFAULT_LEVEL;
            }

            level = getLevel (parent_input);

            if (level != NOT_IN_FILE) {
                insertToMap (input, level);
            }
        }
    }

    return level;
}
```

Comment: the data is copied... something other than what you've shown is wrong...

Comment: the map values are being searched from a different method
so I'm not in the same scope of the code above. the other method is looking for a char* ( map.find((char*)value) ) in this static map that should hold a valid reference to strings from different methods

Comment: You posted 5 lines of (invalid) C++ code, with no context of when, where, or how this code invoked.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I assume its not because you missed a bracket in your example: `map.insert(make_pair(toStr, a);` --> `map.insert(make_pair(toStr, a));` because I don't think that would compile... otherwise the code you have here looks good. As Mark suggests possibly something else is corrupting it, do you have more code?

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://ideone.com/gD0sO0)

Comment: thanks, I added the relevant code section

Comment: `char parent_input[len];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays must be declared using compile-time expressions, not runtime (variables).   Why are you no using `std::string` for this character data?  Also this is so inefficient, I won't even need to comment:  `unsigned int len = ((strlen(ROOT_LEVEL) > strlen(input)) ? strlen(ROOT_LEVEL) :`

Answer (score 1):

> What can cause the data to be corrupted?

I am willing to bet that the problem is related to order of initialization of global variables. I recommend replacing

```
static map<string, int> levelMap;
```

with a function.

```
static map<string, int>& getLevelMap()
{
   static map<string, int> theMap;
   return theMap;
}
```

This guarantees that `theMap` is properly initialized when another function calls `getLevelMap()`.

Comment: It seems like the root issue is that the destructor is calling a function that  prints what is stored in the map, but the key(std::string) value was released already and it caused memory leak...